# The classes in the module cannot be loaded

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, firebase

I am developing a 2D Unity android game in which i recently added Firebase Beta SDK, but after adding `FirebaseAnalytics.unitypackage` i am facing the error which is :

> The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

When i remove the folder `Firebase` from project the error no more appears. What can be the problem?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your Unity project actually set to platform "Android"?

Comment: Yes it is set Android platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have observed similar error message when using Unity 5.3.5.
Using Unity 5.4.0+ resolved this issue for me.

```
SpritePacker failed to get types from Firebase.App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. Error: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.

Error building Player: ReflectionTypeLoadException: The classes in the module cannot be loaded.
```

This is regarding 1.1.0 version of Firebase.
It was working on 1.0.1 version correctly.

Comment: Thank you FirebaseUser, updating Unity fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks ! Same issue for me with unity 5.3+, updating to 5.4 solved the problem